# How to get this piece of practice of json in python3 work properly?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I did a simple practice that will ask the user for their name and favorite number and store them in a dictionary. I used json so that the data can be accessed each time you run the code. The program will ask for the user's name and return their favorite number or ask for their favorite number. It will also ask if the number returned is correct.

ISSUE:
When I run the program multiple times and add or modify some values, all previous value will be removed.

For example, after the first time I ran it, the .json file has
`{'alice':'8', 'bob':'7'}`in it. Then I quit the program. When I ran it again, I can still access Alice and Bob s' favorite numbers. However, if I try to add another person's favorite number, Alice and Bob will be removed. If I try to change Bob's favorite number, Alice will be removed.
Any additional changes after that will not cause more unwanted changes.

Thanks to whoever helps me out.

```
import json

fav_nums = {}
filename = 'fav_number.json'

def user_in_dict(n):
    #check if the user had given a response before#
    with open(filename, 'r') as f_obj:
        fav_nums = json.load(f_obj)
    if n in fav_nums:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def return_fav_num():
    #return their favourite number and ask if it's correct#
    with open(filename, 'r') as f_obj:
        fav_nums = json.load(f_obj)
    print('Is your favourite number ' + fav_nums[username] + '?')
    checker = input('(Y/N)\n')
    if checker == 'Y':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def add_fav_num():
    #add the new key-value pair into the dictionary#
    number = input("What's yout favourite number?\n")
    fav_nums[username] = number
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(fav_nums, f_obj)
    print('Thank you.\n')


while True:
    username = input("What's your name? (enter 'q' to quit)\n").lower()
    if username == 'q':
         break
    else:
        if user_in_dict(username):
            if return_fav_num():
                print('')
                pass
            else:
                add_fav_num()
        else:
            add_fav_num()
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top you set `fav_nums = {}`.

In your functions `user_in_dict(n)` and `return_fav_num(n)` you only set the local `fav_nums` inside the function and not the global one. Therefor the global one stays emty.

In `add_fav_num(n)` you add your user to the global `fav_nums` `{}`, because fav_num is not defined in the function and the gobal version is used.

To fix this you cold either initalize `fav_num` directly with your data or pass `fav_num` as an argument.

I would recommend the second option.